# login to github in a scala web application

Tags: scala, oauth-2.0, github-api

I am a total noob in Scala, I am just learning. So I am writing a server in Scala and I need to login to Github to access a repository. Are there any libraries that implement an OAuth consumer that I could use? I come from Ruby, and there is Warden that I used in the past. I am looking for something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of OAuth, OAuth 1 and OAuth 2. Github uses OAuth 2. The Play Framework authors, for one, consider OAuth 2 sufficiently simple to implement yourself that they don't provide a helper for it.

However, Google says:

"Given the security implications of getting the implementation correct, we strongly encourage developers to use OAuth 2.0 libraries when interacting with Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoints"

(I know Github isn't a Google endpoint, but this security point is valid for any website protected by OAuth.) And Google provides [a generic OAuth 2 client for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth2), and because Java code can be called from Scala, you can use that.

However, note that certain Github API calls (I think it's ones that access public repositories) don't require any authentication.

You will, however, need to set the User-Agent header to the name of your application in each HTTP request.